# I have a problem in my project (medical image classification) output it is always giving me that classes=[[0.]]. so, the prediction is always same

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, image-classification

test model with some images from your local computer to predict whether a patient is affected by cancer or not

```
        import numpy as np
        from google.colab import files
        from keras.preprocessing import image
        uploaded = files.upload()
        for fn in uploaded.keys():
           path='/content/'+fn
           print(path)
           img = image.load_img(path , target_size=(50,50))
           x = image.img_to_array(img)
           x=np.expand_dims(x,axis=0)
           images = np.vstack([x])
           classes = model.predict(images)
           print(classes)
```

Comment: You probably forgot some preprocessing step like normalization that was applied to your training set, you also need to apply the same preprocessing to new images.

Comment: Could you show your pre-processing and post-processing techniques? also the model architechture? Then maybe I can find the error.

Comment: @MushfiratMohaimin This is my email a.dababat2@student.aaup.edu. Could you please  contact me in this email?